Is there a way to scroll up and down to a particular area / element inside a webpage and not the whole webpage itself using Python Selenium?
I'm currently trying to scroll a specific area in this webpage that I am testing because the "Save" button that I need to click is at the bottom and not visible unless you scroll down so whenever I run the script it says "Unable to locate element".
The catch is this particular area has a unique scroll bar, it has no up/down buttons nor have a specific ID, Name, Class, XPATH on it. The whole XPATH is the area / panel that I'm trying to scroll.
I'm using Python Selenium on PyCharm.
I tried ActionsChains like hovering the cursor on the panel first via move_to_element() and then tried scroll_to_element but its still not scrolling downwards and results in unable to locate element.
I also tried JavaScript's execute_script("arguments[0], scrollIntoView(true)", xpath) but it does not do anything as well.
I tried send_keys(Keys.END) but its the whole page that is scrolling down and not the particular area / panel.
Its either the unable to locate element or element not interactable.

Can you share the html associated with the website that you're trying to execute the action on? If you're working with scroll, you'll need to execute the action on the element which listens to the "scroll" event.

In most of the cases, there is an element with the "scrollable" attribute associated to it that caters to all type of scrolling of a specific component.

maybe better create minimal reproducible example which we could simply copy and run. And add link to this page so we could see how it works

I provided at answer below, but its still lacking in some areas

I found the solution to my inquiry.
XPATH_1 = 'xpath_of_scrollable_panel_inside_webpage'
XPATH_2= context.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, XPATH_1)
context.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", XPATH_2)

This script scrolls the scrollable panel inside a webpage all the way to the bottom.

I edited this to remove the follow-up question.  Please use the ask question form to ask additional questions.
